# Meteor js client side connect directly to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Using meteor js on the client side and from this condition: if (Meteor.isClient), is it possible to connect to a mongodb collection directly?

If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's what Meteor is all about! See [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection). Simple example:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Documents = new Meteor.Collection('documents');
  var document = Documents.findOne({title: 'Example'});
}
```